# What can linear stability analysis say about trajectories starting in the neighbourhood of a fixed point? The role of Arnold diffusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, chaos-theory, stability-theory

Consider a Hamiltonian dynamical system having more degrees of freedom than invariant quantities (Suppose that the number of degrees of freedom is $D>1$ and that the only invariant quantity is the Hamiltonian). Let $z^*$ be a fixed point of the motion equations.

Assume that the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix (evaluated at $z^*$) are all such that their real part is null. The fixed point $z^*$ is thus called “elliptic” in the context of linear stability analysis.

What can be said concerning the behaviour of trajectories starting from a point of the phase space very close to $z^*$? Will they remain in the neighbourhood of the fixed point (elliptic periodic orbits)?

If yes, it means that we are observing a regular motion in a system which is non-integrable (recall the hypothesis: more degrees of freedom than conserved quantities). Is this possible? Is there something similar to an invariant torus, despite the system is non-integrable?

If no, it means that chaos eventually shows up due to non-linearities, thus completely destroying the memory of the initial condition. So, what’s the purpose of studying the linear stability analysis of a fixed point?

On top of that, It comes to my mind the ghost of Arnold diffusion, which says that for $D>2$ the invariant tori (if any) cannot topologically separate the phase space into two disconnected regions and thus cannot prevent chaos from percolating in all the phase space. Is this phenomenon related to the issue?

Comment: Just thinking out loud: if all eigenvalues are purely imaginary, but non-zero, then the quadratic part of Hamiltonian is non-degenerate. Combining [Morse lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_lemma) and knowledge about eigenvalues, we can conclude that locally level sets of Hamiltonian look like the level sets of $\sum x_i^2$. It means that topologically level sets are $\mathbb{S}^{2D-1}$. While the trajectories remain close to equilibrium, it doesn't mean that motion on these spheres is regular.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very smart observation. So, we can conclude that a trajectory starting in the neighbourhood of the elliptic fixed point will live on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^(2D-1)$ and therefore it will remain colse to the fixed point (because the radius of this sphere is assumed small). Nevertheless the motion on this spheres is not regular but chaotic. Right?

Comment: Well, I can't guarantee for sure that dynamics is non-regular. I'm not good at analysis of Hamiltonian systems on level sets. You can for sure guarantee that this level set won't have any equilibria on it since your equilibrium is non-degenerate. If you suppose that there are only periodic orbits on it, then (as far as I understand) that would be pretty strong property, but I am not specialist in this stuff either.

Comment: Again, thanks for your nice explanations. As I am from the Physics community, 1) Can you please explain in other words, what you mean with “you can for sure guarantee that this level set won’t have any equilibria on it since your equilibrium is non-degenerate”.

Comment: 2) Do you confirm that the elliptical fixed point is a sphere of the type you‘ve mentioned, having zero radius, and that all other spheres are centered around this point?

Comment: 3) Have you got any idea about how to characterize the motion of trajectories living on the spheres you’ve mentioned? I am particularly interested in distinguishing between cahotic and regular motion.

Comment: 1) If you  have system $\dot{x} = F(x)$, $x_0$ is an equilibrium and $\frac{DF}{Dx}(x_0)$ is non-degenerate as a matrix, then $x_0$ is an isolated equilibrium. It means there is a neighbourhood of $x_0$ that contains no other equilibria. Thus, if we switch back to your system, level sets of Hamiltonian close to equilibrium possess no equilibria — just choose neighbourhood where both Morse lemma and previous observation work and pick level sets that fit into this neighbourhood completely. 2) This is true in coordinates provided by Morse lemma. In another coordinates level sets might not be ...

Comment: ... spheres, but they still surround the equilibrium.

Comment: @Evgeny thanks a lot for you time and patience. Apart from answering point number (3), if you have an hint, can you please tell me what happens, from a topological point of view, when one pair of purely imaginary eigenvalues acquire a real part?

Comment: I've specifically omitted question (3) because I am still in the process of checking what classical books write on this subject. By the way, just the pair of purely imaginary eigenvalues [can't acquire a real part](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Stability_of_Hamiltonian_equilibria): eigenvalues of equilibria of Hamiltonian systems appear in quadruples ($z$, $-z$, $\overline{z}$ and $-\overline{z}$), so you need a merge of four eigenvalues at imaginary axis before acquiring a real part.

Comment: Ok, well. This is another valuable info. So I reformulate my question: what happens to the hyperspheres when these two pairs of purely imaginary eigenvalues merge and acquire a real part? (By the way, sorry of rushing you about point (3)).

Comment: Ah, very important. When you say that the Jacobian associated to the dynamical system and evaluated at the elliptic fixed point ($\frac{DF}{Dx}(x_0)$) is NON-degenerate, do you mean “invertibile”, i.e. with determinant different from zero? What happens, instead, if some (but not all) pairs of eigenvalues of the Jacobian is vanishing? Are the level sets still hyperspheres? Does their dimensionality diminish?

Comment: Yes, I mean that matrix $\frac{DF}{Dx}(x_0)$ is invertible. In any other cases you will have a continuum of equilibria in the neighbourhood of $x_0$ — I don't think that you really want that, don't you? I am not really sure, but level sets of function around critical point are hyperspheres iff the point is a strict maximum or minimum; and if it is true, the degeneracy of $\frac{DF}{Dx}$ prevents having such level sets.

Comment: Speaking about the books, take a look at chapter 19.10 of [Wiggins](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387001777) and chapter 9 of [Meiss's book](https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Dynamical-Monographs-Mathematical-Computation/dp/0898716357).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very good references. Reading pag. 223 of Wiggins, I've noticed that the "energy surfaces are locally diffeomorphic to a family of spheres", provided that the "equilibrium point as index zero", so that the Hamiltonian is "locally conjugate to a Hamiltonian of the form" $\sum_{j=1}^n(q_j^2+p_j^2)$. So there seems to be an additional assumption concerning the signature of the Hessian matrix in order to be able to state the energy surfaces are locally diffeomorphic to a family of spheres. Isn't there?

Comment: You are probably right. Some time ago I thought that there is a simple relation between eigenvalues of two matrices: $\nabla^2 H (x_0)$ and $J \nabla^2 H(x_0)$, where $H$ is Hamiltonian, $\nabla^2 H$ is a Hesse matrix of Hamiltonian and $J = \left ( \begin{array}{cc}  0 & E\\ -E & 0\end{array} \right)$. Matrix $J \nabla^2 H(x_0)$ is a fancy way to write Jacobi matrix at equilibrium $x_0$, which determines the linearized dynamics. If matrix $\nabla^2 H (x_0)$ is non-singular, it determines the structure of level sets around $H(x_0)$. ...

Comment: ... I thought that if $J \nabla^2 H(x_0)$ has $\pm i \omega_j$ as only eigenvalues, then $\nabla^2 H(x_0)$ is a positive- or negative-definite matrix automatically and then level sets of $H$ around $x_0$ are automatically topological hyperspheres. But I can't find a reference for it or prove it myself, so you might be right about requiring something additional.

Comment: It is indeed true that the Jacobi matrix at equilibtrium $x_0$ can be written as $J\nabla^2H(x_0)$. By the way, in case the Hesse matrix is positive- or negative- definite, the possibility of locally writing it as $\sum_{j=1}^n (q_j^2+p_j^2)$ makes the relevant motion regular, as it is the sum of independent harmonic oscillators. Right?!

Comment: As far as I understand Morse's lemma doesn't guarantee that this change of variables is canonical from the point of view of Hamiltonian systems: a system in these new coordinates won't be derived from Hamiltonian $\sum_{j=1}^n (q_j^2+p_j^2)$. Chapter 19.10 in Wiggins explains what kind of equations you can obtain in this case using canonical transformations.

Comment: You're absolutely right.

Comment: By the way, there is a way out. Take a look at p. 386 in [Arnold's book](https://loshijosdelagrange.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/v-arnold-mathematical-methods-of-classical-mechanics-1989.pdf): using the result for quadratic Hamiltonians, he states that in case of $\pm i \omega_j$ as only eigenvalues, the quadratic part of Hamiltonian can be always reduced to $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\omega_j}{2} (q_j^2 + p_j^2)$. So, in case of such eigenvalues the quadratic part of Hamiltonian is indeed always positive definite.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I've seen what you've quoted. But, the line below says "(Some of the numbers $\omega_k$ may be negative)". So I guess that, in case one or more $\omega_k$ is negative, the level set of $H$ are not diffeomorphic to a family of spheres. Am I wrong?

Comment: ... and so the quadratic part of Hamiltonian is not necessarily always positive definite.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I've misread that bit. I think I'll try to reread my references once more again.

Comment: Ok. Nevertheless, pages 385-386-387 include many explanations. As I am not an expert of this field, I find two statements apparently contrasting. At first he says "It is useful to choose a canonical coordinate system near the equilibrium point" -> But "in a Hamiltonian system the "reduction of the Hamiltonian field to a linear normal form by a canonical change of variables is generally not possible". Nevertheless "this difficulty can be surmounted by the choice of a nonlinear normal form". "As a result, in the non-resonance case" we can introduce action-angle viariables ...

Comment: ... near an equilibrium position so that the system becomes integrable up to terms of arbitrary high degree in the Taylor series". "This method allows us to study the behaviour of system over the course of large intervals of time for initial conditions close to equilibrium". However it is not sufficient do determine Liapunov stability (since for $t\to+\infty$), the remainder of the truncated Taylor series can destroy the stability). Liapunov stability would be present if an exact reduction was possible (= no disregarding of the remainder). "However we can show that this exact reduction is..."

Comment: "... generally not possible, and formal series for canonical transformations reducing a system to normal forms usually diverge". The divergence of this series is connected to the fact that this exact reduction would imply a simpler behavior (=conditionally periodic winding of tori) than what actually is.

Comment: Then he says "Suppose that in the \textit{linear} approximation an equilibrium position of an hamiltonian system is stable" (eigenvalues $\pm i\omega_j$). Then the quadratic part of the Hamiltonian can be reduced to a normal form by a canonical \textit{linear} transformation. And then "A hamiltonian in normal form is integrable".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77925/discussion-between-andreapaco-and-evgeny).